# Tomcat timeouts when booting (spring maven hibernate)

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, tomcat

Previous question for reference:
[Hibernate 4 + Spring 4 + Maven + Apache Tomcat 8.0 init failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28458323/hibernate-4-spring-4-maven-apache-tomcat-8-0-init-failed?noredirect=1#comment45256663_28458323)

I have created a brand new project and now Tomcat does not even run. It timeouts after 45 seconds(I have changed it to 180, but it still timeouts then). Here is console output. It gets 'stuck' after last line. What might cause the proble?

```
lut 12, 2015 2:10:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.17
lut 12, 2015 2:10:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Jan 9 2015 15:58:59 UTC
lut 12, 2015 2:10:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.0.17.0
lut 12, 2015 2:10:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 8.1
lut 12, 2015 2:10:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.3
lut 12, 2015 2:10:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
lut 12, 2015 2:10:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JAVA_HOME:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25
lut 12, 2015 2:10:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_25-b18
lut 12, 2015 2:10:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
lut 12, 2015 2:10:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Tomek\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
lut 12, 2015 2:10:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0
lut 12, 2015 2:10:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Tomek\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
lut 12, 2015 2:10:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0
lut 12, 2015 2:10:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\Tomek\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
lut 12, 2015 2:10:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\endorsed
lut 12, 2015 2:10:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1250
lut 12, 2015 2:10:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_31/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_31/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_31/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Users\Tomek\Desktop\eclipse;;.
lut 12, 2015 2:10:54 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
lut 12, 2015 2:10:54 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
lut 12, 2015 2:10:54 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
lut 12, 2015 2:10:54 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
lut 12, 2015 2:10:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 551 ms
lut 12, 2015 2:10:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
lut 12, 2015 2:10:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.17
lut 12, 2015 2:10:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Users\Tomek\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf\Catalina\localhost\HelloWorld.xml
lut 12, 2015 2:10:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:HelloWorld' did not find a matching property.
lut 12, 2015 2:10:57 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
lut 12, 2015 2:10:57 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
lut 12, 2015 2:10:57 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
lut 12, 2015 2:10:57 AM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Feb 12 02:10:57 CET 2015]; root of context hierarchy
lut 12, 2015 2:10:57 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]
lut 12, 2015 2:10:58 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
lut 12, 2015 2:10:58 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.6.Final}
lut 12, 2015 2:10:59 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
lut 12, 2015 2:10:59 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out i had wrong port defined here, should have been 5342 instead of 8080:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5342/testdb"/>
    <property name="username" value="postgres"/>
    <property name="password" value="im not that stupid"/>
    <property name="initialSize" value="3" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="10" />
</bean>
```